# I need to re-enter my ruby on rails sqlite console so I can do sqlite commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

To get back into my app's sqlite db console (sqlite>), I believe I use, rails console db? Well when I did that I got back this,

```
MacBook-Pro:fancy_cars $ rails db console

/Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb:100:in `config': 'console' database is not configured. Available configuration: {"default"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}, "development"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/development.sqlite3"}, "test"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/test.sqlite3"}, "production"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/production.sqlite3"}} (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb:22:in `start'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb:11:in `start'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:86:in `dbconsole'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/apples/fancy_cars/bin/rails:9:in `require'

from /Users/apples/fancy_cars/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/apples/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

from /Users/jasonbrown/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

from /Users/jasonbrown/fancy_cars/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'

from bin/rails:3:in `load'

from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help me with what to do?

Answer (score 2):

You're close. You want this:

```
rails dbconsole
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-dbconsole for more information. You can also use a shorter version:

```
rails db
```